# Removing class when iOS keyboard is open (HTML/JS/CSS)

Tags: javascript, ios, keyboard

I would like to remove my `.textareafooter` class when i tap the `textarea` field in iOS via JS/JQuery.

Explanation:

My .textareafooter is a white DIV right below my container with the `textarea` which has a `bottom-boder-radius` nested in a DIV with a black background.

If the keyboard pops in then i've got ontop of the keyboard the said footer which looks horrible.

I photoshopped this picture below just quickly to kinda illustrate my problem.

[image: Symbolic Pic]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to first check if the device is an Iphone. You do that by using the [Navigator Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator). And then remove the class from the textArea.

```js
let textArea = document.querySelector('.textareafooter')

textArea.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    
    //Check if it is an iphone device
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iphone') > - 1) {
        
        //Remove the class
        
        textArea.classList.remove('textareafooter')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try arranging CSS

```
textarea:has(:focus) + .textareafooter


textareaParent:focus-within .textareafooter


aspect-ratio
```

or JavaScript

```
textarea.addEventListener('focus', ...)


textarea.addEventListener('blur' ...)
```